# Where I can find the url of native Android and iOS application

Tags: javascript, android, ios

I want to open iOS and android application from my HTML page . I have tried music application of iOS successfully using :

```
window.location = "music://";
```

and map application of android using:

```
window.location = "geo://"
```

but the problem is I wanted to open more applications like gallery , contacts etc. I have tried different combinations of url but not able to open those . where can I find the urls for the native applications in android and iOS .

Comment: For iOS, go to iTunes Store, search for your application, right click on the app icon and select copy link. There you have the link of application on your clipboard.

Comment: For iOS here is list of [application URL schemes](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes). They are subject to change hence your functionalities may break.

Answer (score 0):

**Window Location Pathname**

The location.pathname property returns the path name of a URL.

**Window Location**

The window.location object can be written without the window prefix.

Some examples:

1.location.hostname returns the domain name of the web host

2.location.pathname returns the path and filename of the current page

1. location.port returns the port of the web host (80 or 443)
2. location.protocol returns the web protocol used (http:// or https://)
   Window Location Href

The location.href property returns the URL of the current page.

Example

Return the entire URL (of the current page):

```
<script>

document.write(location.href);

</script>
```

The output of the code above is:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp